# Start archiving in opentok java sdk v4.3.0 results in 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: java, spring, opentok, tokbox

I am using tokbox opentok project for publishing and subscribing video camera and also archiving them. I was using opentok-java-sdk v2.3.2 in which everything was working fine until I changed the sdk version. Now I have changed the sdk version to 4.3.0. which is resulting in start archiving failure.
It gives me the following error:

```
com.opentok.exception.RequestException: Could not start an OpenTok Archive. A bad request, check input archive properties like resolution etc.
    at com.opentok.util.HttpClient.startArchive(HttpClient.java:259)
    at com.opentok.OpenTok.startArchive(OpenTok.java:445)
    at com.abc.web.utils.OpenTokSdkUtils.startRecording(OpenTokSdkUtils.java:99)
```

If anyone could help me out with this. That would be really appreciated.
**Edit:-** I am following this code from the opentok guide for java sdk

```
import com.opentok.Archive;
import com.opentok.ArchiveProperties;

Archive archive = opentok.startArchive(sessionId, new ArchiveProperties.Builder()
  .archiveMode(Archive.OutputMode.INDIVIDUAL)
  .build());

// Store this archiveId in the database for later use
String archiveId = archive.getId();
```

But this has a problem with ArchiveBuilder as archive builder has no method name archiveMode, so I used the outputMode which I was using previously.
After changes:-

```
Archive archive = opentok.startArchive(sessionId, new ArchiveProperties.Builder()
                      .outputMode(Archive.OutputMode.INDIVIDUAL).name(username)
                      .build());
```

Comment: TokBox Developer Evangelist here. Could you please share the request that you're making?

Comment: @Manik, I have added the code that I am using to make the request.

Comment: Anshul, Thanks for sharing the code and finding the typo. You are right - it should be outputMode not archiveMode. I've filed an issue on the repo to fix the documentation: https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-Java-SDK/issues/173

Did the archive work for you after changing it to `outputMode`? Please also note that you cannot specify the resolution for individual archiving - that feature is only available for composed archives.

Comment: No, it didn't work. I have kept it to outputMode only and I did not add the resolution to the archiving but still, it is not working. The case in which it is working is when I remove the `ArchiveProperties` from the `startArchive` method it works fine in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

It looks like the [OpenTok Java SDK](https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-Java-SDK/) is attempting to add a layout even when the `outputMode` is set to `Archive.OutputMode.INDIVIDUAL`. I've gone ahead and filed a [bug](https://github.com/opentok/Opentok-Java-SDK/issues/174) in the SDK repo so you can track the patch release.

Please check out the API docs for more information on archiving: https://tokbox.com/developer/rest/#start_archive

Comment: Thanks for the help really appreciated. And does that mean I won't be able to use the archive properties till the fix gets released or is there any workaround?